# send a specific queryset to all templates

Tags: django, django-channels

I have a Django application which has notification.It uses Django channels this way that it takes user id in view and then at templates uses json_script to make the id a JS object.
So i have to write the bellow code every where

```
user=user.id  
context={....,"user":user}
```

How can i write it one instead of every where?

Comment: No, if you use `render(request, ...)`, it will automatically add `user` to the context of the template (as well as `request`).

Comment: it's not well documented with examples, but check what are Template Context Processors (inside `settings.TEMPLATES.OPTIONS.context_processors`), which is a list of functions and their return value is passed into each rendered template.